# Firefox error 'setting a property that only has a getter' when calling Array.prototype.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox

I need to convert a `NodeList` object to an array - in this case, a list of `<div>` elements, as I need to use the `map()` and `filter()` methods to refine it.

Unfortunately in Firefox (I tested both 3.6 and 4) the method I'm using throws the following error:

```
Error: setting a property that only has a getter
```

The following code is a condensed version of line in question.

```
trackList = [].splice.call(videoElement.querySelectorAll("div"),0);
```

This works fine in Chrome and Safari. It doesn't appear to be related to the `querySelectAll` method as the same issue occurs regardless of how the `NodeList` is obtained (e.g. with `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`.)

The issue appears to lie with the `call()` method itself - given a preexisting `NodeList` and reference to the `Array.prototype.slice` method, the following will still fail:

```
sliceMethod.call(myNodeList,0);
```

Needless to say, I'm stumped - any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

This turned out to be a typographical error - *slice* instead of *splice* was intended.

Comment: After posting my answer, I tried `Array.prototype.splice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'), 0);` in [jsconsole](http://jsconsole.com/) and it worked fine. I still think you probably meant to use `slice` but it looks like my answer was wrong. Can you post a minimal example demonstrating this apparent bug on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not with `call` but with the NodeList. NodeLists are (I think always) live, meaning that if a new div is added, it automatically becomes part of the NodeList, or if it is removed from the document, it is also removed from the NodeList, etc. Thus it doesn't make sense to take anything out of the NodeList, which is what `splice` does. I think probably you meant to use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead.

Comment: Ack! You're exactly right! I've been staring at this code all day long (as has my colleague) and we didn't pick up the error. Goes to show having other people look at your work helps! Thanks :)